# jQuery .Show() not working if negative margin in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, show

Here is a Codepen for this issue that you can use to see the problem: http://codepen.io/theclarkofben/pen/xKhsd

As you can see the `.Show()` effect is not functioning correctly because of the negative margin I have applied to the div.

***Can anyone help explain why this is happening?***

***Is there a way I can use negative margin with this method without the problem?***

I'm using Chrome. I have tried different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI but same problem is seen.

```js
$(function() {
  // run the currently selected effect
  function runEffect() {
    // get effect type from
    var selectedEffect = "clip";

    // most effect types need no options passed by default
    var options = {};
    // run the effect
    $("#show_effect").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback);
  };

  //callback function to bring a hidden box back
  function callback() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#show_effect:visible").removeAttr("style").fadeOut();
    }, 1000);
  };

  // set effect from select menu value
  $("#about_me_button").click(function() {
    runEffect();
  });

  $("#show_effect").hide();
});
```

```css
.about_me {
  width: 600px;
  height: 225px;
  margin-right: -300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="about_me_button">About Me</button>
<div id="show_effect" class="about_me">
  <p>Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris
    ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum
    appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper
    feugait vituperatoribus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working perfectly for me... what did you expect happening and did not happen? by the way, `show` uses the `display` style property, if you want to 'move' `margin` you should probably use `animate` instead...

Comment: May I know why you want to keep negative margin on right?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"Show() effect is not functioning correctly"*..?  what is expected and what is happening..?

Comment: How about using `margin-left:300px` instead?

Comment: By the way, i can't find a signature in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/) where it accepts 4 arguments...

Comment: @webeno @T J  the effect only executes on half of the paragraph. when you watch it you'll see that half of the paragraph doesn't transition.

Comment: @T J  see here where it states: .show( effect [, options ] [, duration ] [, complete ] )  http://api.jqueryui.com/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..

Since I waited and couldn't find out why you want to use negative margin. I came up with two approaches for you..

1 - **Use `margin-left:300px` instead of `margin-right:-300px`** - 
It removes the flicker effect yet does the same job..

```
.about_me {
  width: 600px;
  height: 225px;
  margin-left:300px
}
```

2 - **Introduce parent container for `<div class="about-me">` and give it a style `margin-right:-300px`**.

Codepen here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zHfbC
HTML :

```
<div class="about_me_container">
  <div  id="show_effect" class="about_me">
     <p>About me goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.about_me {
  width: 600px;
  height: 225px;

}

.about_me_container{
  margin-right:-300px;
}
```

Hope that helps you!

Regards,
**RP**

Comment: thank you for your help. in the example i made for this here i used negative right margin just so i could put together something simple. my actual CSS has position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -[half of the div width]%;. that's why i'm trying to use negative margin. can you explain how adding a container div has fixed this? i can't understand why my code caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `margin-right` css to 300px on button click and in callback reset that to -300px. I have tried that it is working fine. Hope i understand your requirement now! [Example - codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ugCEA)

```js
  $(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = "clip";

      // most effect types need no options passed by default
      var options = {};
      // run the effect
      $(".about_me").css("margin-right", "300px");
      $("#show_effect").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback);
    };

    //callback function to bring a hidden box back
    function callback() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#show_effect:visible").removeAttr("style").fadeOut();
        $(".about_me").css("margin-right", "-300px");
      }, 1000);
    };

    // set effect from select menu value
    $("#about_me_button").click(function() {
      runEffect();
    });

    $("#show_effect").hide();
  });
```

```css
.about_me {
  width: 600px;
  height: 225px;
  margin-right: -300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="about_me_button">About Me</button>
<div id="show_effect" class="about_me">
  <p>Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris
    ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum
    appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper
    feugait vituperatoribus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. can you explain what i did wrong and how you fixed it? i'm reading your code but the explanation isn't obvious to me.

Comment: you can see that in `runeffect` function i have changed margin to positive number using ` $(".about_me").css("margin-right", "300px");` and in `callback`, i have again reverted that to negative value!

Comment: yes, thanks i understood that. but what i don't understand is what was going wrong with my code that led you to this as a solution?

Comment: you are using `margin` as negative value, that led to flickering html animation, to make it work, i have made it positive temporarily.

Comment: i guess my question is why is negative margin causing the problem? what is it about negative margin that makes it do that? if i understand why then i can learn from that and not do anything related in the future that would cause the same problem.

Comment: negative margin, reserved more space in right, than it actually requires, and that clashed with jquery animation, leading to flickering. Check with negative margin - http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/3wc8b0ah/1/, see the horizontal scroll, and with positive margin or remove that attribute - http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/3wc8b0ah/2/, there is no space reserved , no scrollbar.